The order of Dependency Property and DataContext assignment
From my testing, it seems that the DataContext seems to be always assigned first before the assignment of Dependency Property, if I only set the DataContext and the Dependency Property once via XAML ( see the example below).
But is this always true? Is there a C# language spec that says-- no, guarantees -- this? I need this because my program depends precisely on this behavior.
Here's the code that I can use to illustrate this point:
View Models
public class MainWindowVM
{
    public SimpleTextBoxVM SimpleText => new SimpleTextBoxVM();
}
public class SimpleTextBoxVM
{
}

public class Updater
{
}

UI
public class Updater
{
}

public partial class SimpleTextBoxExt : UserControl
{
    public SimpleTextBoxExt()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContextChanged += OnDataContextChanged;
    }

    private void OnDataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DataContext Assigned."); //this seems always executed first

        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FractionalNumberProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(FractionalNumber), typeof(Updater), typeof(SimpleTextBoxExt), new PropertyMetadata(default(Updater), PropertyChangedCallback));

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (d is SimpleTextBoxExt simpleTextBox)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Dependency property set"); //this seems always executed later
        }
    }



    public Updater FractionalNumber
    {
        get { return (Updater)GetValue(FractionalNumberProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FractionalNumberProperty, value); }
    }
}

<Window x:Class="DependencyPropertiesUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DependencyPropertiesUI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
   <Window.DataContext>
       <local:MainWindowVM/>
   </Window.DataContext>
    <local:SimpleTextBoxExt DataContext="{Binding SimpleText}">
        <local:SimpleTextBoxExt.FractionalNumber>
            <local:Updater/>
        </local:SimpleTextBoxExt.FractionalNumber>
    </local:SimpleTextBoxExt>
</Window>


The DataContext can change at any time, as well as the value of all other dependency properties. This depends solely on how your control is used, e.g. whether properties are set directly or by data binding. You should write code that handles both.

@Clemens, I only set the DataContext and the Dependency Property once via XAML; see the code sample above. I've also updated the question.

I'd say the order of property value assignments made by the XAML Parser is an implementation detail of the framework. I would not rely on anything here.

Your question is not really clear. DataContext is also a dependency property. All dependency properties of a type are initialized with their default value that was specified by the PropertyM;etadata object. The order of property initialization is from base type to derived type. Because DataContext is defined on the base type it will be initialized before properties of your derived type. These are language rules of type initialization. But you should not rely on this. The first value is only the default. It will likely change during the initialization routine when the context is evaluated.

The short answer is no, DataContext doesn't always get set first. It can appear that way sometimes because changing DataContext causes DataContext-dependent properties which are already bound (but might have no value yet) to be re-assigned, but it all still follows the same order of assignment as other DPs, which is:

Inherited properties, including potentially DataContext.

Directly-assigned properties, in XAML order, including potentially DataContext a second time (if also inherited).

Bound properties, including potentially DataContext a second time (if also inherited), also in XAML order. When DataContext is bound, if DataContext-bound properties have already been bound and have a value from a prior inherited DataContext, they'll be re-set after the DataContext changes but before other bound properties in XAML order.


I'm uncertain of whether or where all this is documented (other than scouring the WPF source), but a few examples illustrate this clearly.
Given the following custom control:
public class MyCustomControl : Control
{
    public MyCustomControl()
    {
        this.DataContextChanged += this.MyCustomControl_DataContextChanged;
    }

    #region string MyProperty dependency property
    public static DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyProperty",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(MyCustomControl),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            null,
            (obj, args) =>
            {
                ((MyCustomControl)obj).OnMyPropertyChanged(args);
            }));
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value);
        }
    }
    private void OnMyPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MyProperty Changed to {args.NewValue}");
    }
    #endregion

    #region string MyOtherProperty dependency property
    public static DependencyProperty MyOtherPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MyOtherProperty",
        typeof(string),
        typeof(MyCustomControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            null,
            (obj, args) =>
            {
                ((MyCustomControl)obj).OnMyOtherPropertyChanged(args);
            }));
    public string MyOtherProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(MyOtherPropertyProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(MyOtherPropertyProperty, value);
        }
    }
    private void OnMyOtherPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"MyOtherProperty Changed to {args.NewValue}");
    }
    #endregion

    private void MyCustomControl_DataContextChanged(object sender, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"DataContext Changed to {e.NewValue}");
    }
}

We can see what happens in different scenarios.
Example 1
    <so:MyCustomControl DataContext="Blue"
                        MyOtherProperty="Orange"
                        MyProperty="Green" />
    <so:MyCustomControl MyProperty="Green"
                        DataContext="Blue" 
                        MyOtherProperty="Orange" />

Result
DataContext Changed to Blue
MyOtherProperty Changed to Orange
MyProperty Changed to Green
MyProperty Changed to Green
DataContext Changed to Blue
MyOtherProperty Changed to Orange

When all properties are direct-assigns the order simply depends on the order in XAML. DataContext gets no special treatment.

Example 2
    <TextBlock x:Name="_textBlock"
               Text="Orange" />
    <so:MyCustomControl MyProperty="{Binding}"
                        MyOtherProperty="Red"                            
                        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_textBlock, Path=Text}" />

Result
MyOtherProperty Changed to Red
DataContext Changed to Orange
MyProperty Changed to Orange

We see that MyOtherProperty (the direct assign) goes first, followed by DataContext and then MyProperty. Even though MyProperty appears earlier in XAML order and is in fact bound before DataContext (which we'll verify in the next example), it has no value prior to DataContext being set.

Example 3
<Grid DataContext="Blue">
    <TextBlock x:Name="_textBlock"
               Text="Orange" />
    <so:MyCustomControl MyProperty="{Binding}"
                        MyOtherProperty="Red"                            
                        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_textBlock, Path=Text}" />
</Grid>

Result
DataContext Changed to Blue
MyOtherProperty Changed to Red
MyProperty Changed to Blue
DataContext Changed to Orange
MyProperty Changed to Orange

The only change here is to add an inherited DataContext via the parent Grid, which we see now takes precedence. Then MyOtherProperty (a direct-set). Next MyProperty is bound and gets its value from the inherited DataContext. Next the overridden DataContext bound to the TextBlock, changing its value and re-setting MyProperty. This demonstrates that MyProperty is in fact bound before DataContext, just like in Example 2, but unlike in Example 2 MyProperty has an initial value at the time it's bound, because of the inherited context, and so the change handler is invoked twice.

Example 4
<Grid DataContext="Blue">
    <TextBlock x:Name="_textBlock"
               Text="Orange" />
    <so:MyCustomControl MyOtherProperty="Red"                            
                        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_textBlock, Path=Text}"
                        MyProperty="{Binding}" />
</Grid>

Result
DataContext Changed to Blue
MyOtherProperty Changed to Red
DataContext Changed to Orange
MyProperty Changed to Orange

Conversely if we put DataContext before MyProperty, it is bound first, and by the time MyProperty is bound, the inherited DataContext has been overridden and MyProperty is only set once, to Orange.

Example 5
<Grid DataContext="Blue">
    <TextBlock x:Name="_textBlock"
               Text="Orange" />
    <so:MyCustomControl MyProperty="{Binding}"
                        DataContext="{Binding ElementName=_textBlock, Path=Text}"
                        MyOtherProperty="{Binding ElementName=_textBlock, Path=Text}" />
</Grid>

Result
DataContext Changed to Blue
MyProperty Changed to Blue
DataContext Changed to Orange
MyProperty Changed to Orange
MyOtherProperty Changed to Orange

Finally we see here that the bound properties are bound in XAML order. MyProperty gets its initial value from the inherited DataContext, then the inherited DataContext is overridden, then MyProperty is reset to match the new context, and MyOtherProperty is finally bound and set.

Having said all this, while this may be interesting academically, it's still not a great practice to rely on the order of property assignments in XAML or due to DataContext changes. As you can see even though it's generally predictable if you know all the rules, it's still a lot to keep track of and very easy to do something to inadvertently affect assignment order. XAML code-behind and view model code alike should be tolerant of properties being changed in any order, and even multiple times, prior to UI updates.

In general, a custom control must not depend on its DataContext or the DataContext of other elements. That's an anti-pattern. The DataContext is for external bindings or data templating. The DataContext should be expected and allowed to change externally depending on where the control is located.
If a custom control depends on external data, then it must define dependency properties that those data can be assigned to e.g. via data binding. Like any other framework control.
A custom control is initialized and configured by the client via properties (and not via an internal view model).
For example, Button gets the ICommand it executes from the Button.Command property and not from the DataContext. Because it does not define a DataContext internally you can comfortably bind Button.Command to your own data context. The Button internally does not know about its DataContext.
If Button had defined a DataContext internally, the following binding would fail:
<!--
     From client perspective, the DataContext is unexpectedly broken 
     and implicit bindings on properties of this element 
     won't resolve anymore.
     You would never ever expect that the control has overridden the external DataContext! 
     You would look for the error somewhere else...
-->
<Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />

This leads to the next anti-pattern: a view model per control. It should make sense now that a control does not need a view model as it does not depend on any DataContext.
In other words, if you avoid anti-patterns you avoid a lot of problems like race conditions between events or initialization of type members. Relying on such details always leads to brittle code.
From a design pattern point of view MVVM is an architectural design pattern that describes an application structure. The pattern itself does not care about data binding and individual controls. Data binding is the technology that helps to realize the required dependency graph.
The following example highlights the correct design of control.
As you can see, it completely eliminates the race condition issue of your original version. The custom control is DataContext agnostic which, in addition, makes it highly reusable. For example, native WPF controls are reusable because they don't depend on their DataContext:
SimpleTextBoxExt.xaml.cs
public partial class SimpleTextBoxExt : UserControl
{
  // A property to retrieve external data.
  // This data can be internally processed and/or displayed by child elements.
  // No data context necessary.
  public string SomeText
  {
    get => (string)GetValue(SomeTextProperty);
    set => SetValue(SomeTextProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "SomeText",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(SimpleTextBoxExt),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public SimpleTextBoxExt()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }
}

SimpleTextBoxExt.xaml
<UserControl x:Name="Root">

  <!-- 
       Get external data from the parent's dependency properties that are set 
       by the client of this control, e.g. via data binding. 
  -->
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=SomeText}" />
</UserControl>

MainWindow.xaml
<Window>
  <Window.DataContext>
    <MainViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <!-- 
       Feed external data to the custom control or configure the 
       custom control by using dedicated properties. 
  -->
  <SimpleTextBoxExt SomeText="{Binding ViewModelTextValue}" />
</Window>

